# Data using Dynamic Column Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

All - I would like to achieve below using Oracle SQL query (Not PL/SQL) . Please let me know if its achievable

**TABLE 1**

```
Column Name : ONLY_COLUMN

Values: 

COLUMN1

COLUMN5

COLUMN3
```

**TABLE 2**

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4 COLUMN5

V1       V2       V3      V4      V5
```

---

**QUERY OUTPUT**

```
(SELECT_COLUMN_VALUE_FROM_TABLE 1)  (VALUE_FROM_CORRESPONDING_COLUMN_FROM_TABLE 2)
```

COLUMN1                                    V1

COLUMN5                                    V5

COLUMN3                                    V3

---

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure SQL only when the list of columns is fixed, like you have in your case.

```
with tbl1 as (
  select 'COLUMN1' only_column from dual union all
  select 'COLUMN5' only_column from dual union all
  select 'COLUMN3' only_column from dual
),
tbl2 as (
  select 'V1' COLUMN1, 'V2' COLUMN2, 'V3' COLUMN3, 'V4' COLUMN4,'V5' COLUMN5 from dual
)
select only_column,
       case only_column
         when 'COLUMN1' then COLUMN1
         when 'COLUMN2' then COLUMN2
         when 'COLUMN3' then COLUMN3
         when 'COLUMN4' then COLUMN4
         when 'COLUMN5' then COLUMN5
       end res
from   tbl2, tbl1
```

Output:

```
ONLY_COLUMN RES
----------
COLUMN1 V1
COLUMN5 V5
COLUMN3 V3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table tst (col varchar2(10));
create table tst1 (c1 varchar2(10), c2 varchar2(10), c3 varchar2(10), c4 varchar2(10), c5 varchar2(10));
insert into tst values ('c1');
insert into tst values ('c5');
insert into tst values ('c3');
insert into tst1 values ('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5');

Select tst.col, 
case 
    when tst.col = 'c1' then tst1.c1
    when tst.col = 'c2' then tst1.c2
    when tst.col = 'c3' then tst1.c3
    when tst.col = 'c4' then tst1.c4
    when tst.col = 'c5' then tst1.c5
end as val
From tst, tst1
```

Answer (score 0):

With unpivot this is quite straigt forward:

```
with tbl1 as (
  select 'COLUMN1' only_column from dual union all
  select 'COLUMN5' only_column from dual union all
  select 'COLUMN3' only_column from dual
),
tbl2 as (
  select 'V1' COLUMN1, 'V2' COLUMN2, 'V3' COLUMN3, 'V4' COLUMN4,'V5' COLUMN5 from dual
),
piv2 as (
    select * 
    from   tbl2
    unpivot( val for col in (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5))
)
select only_column, val from tbl1,piv2
where piv2.col = tbl1.only_column
```

Result:

```
ONLY_COLUMN VAL
----------- ---
COLUMN1     V1
COLUMN3     V3
COLUMN5     V5
```